# Collect build artifacts from subprojects into RPM with Gradle

Tags: gradle, rpm, multi-project

I have the following project structure:

```
Root
+---Sub1
|
+---Sub2
```

`Sub1` project produces JAR, `Sub2` creates WAR.
`Root` project goal is to produce RPM that contains both the `Sub1` and `Sub2` output.

I'm trying to use `ospackage` Gradle plugin to build RPM. Here is part of root `build.gradle`:

```
ospackage {
    from subprojects.collect { it.tasks.withType(Zip) } into 'lib'
}
```

It works but for `Sub2` both JAR and WAR are created, which is undesirable.

What configuration should be applied in order to collect appropriate jars and wars into RPM?

**UPDATE**

I'm searching for some generic solution, i.e. iteration over subprojects is preferable to specifying behaviour for each subproject.

Comment: Can you not do `project('Sub1').tasks.withType(Jar)` and `project('Sub2').tasks.withType(War)`

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that number of subprojects varies, so it would be great to apply some generic, polymorphic feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add WAR plugin in `Sub2` project's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

make `buildRpm` task dependent on all subprojects build tasks in the root build file:

```
buildRpm.dependsOn getTasksByName('build', true)
```

and finally configure `ospackage` plugin to collect the artifacts into the target RPM:

```
ospackage {
    from(subprojects.collect { "${it.buildDir}/libs" }) {
        into 'bin'
    }
}
```